# Переполнение Metaspace

Tags: java

В Java, начиная с 8 версии, появилась новая вариация **OutOfMemory error : Metaspace**.

Происходит это в связи с переполнением этой самой области памяти, которая является по сути эквивалентом **Permanent Generation**, однако может динамически расширяться.

Вопрос опытным товарищам:
Возникали ли у вас подобные ситуации в вашей практике, за исключением случаев, когда использовались сторонние библиотеки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [тут](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2013/02/java-8-from-permgen-to-metaspace.html) еще в 2013 году описывали работу Metaspace с примером переполнения без использования сторонних библиотек. Попробуйте, может взлетит.